# How set session context in SQL for RLS in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a web api developed in .Net Core 3.1 which talks to Azure SQL db and running as Azure web app. The database a single database of a multi-tenant app and is protected by [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15). It requires to set session context before executing any SQL statement. The session context is the primary key of tenant table which is an integer.

I've learned that I can use [EF Core Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) and set session context. However for security reasons we cannot send/receive tenant id in the URL as a parameter hence we are using another identifier which looks like an encrypted string.
Considering we have a tenant identifier what is the most efficient way to set session context as tenant id? The API is stateless so I can't use session and the controller doesn't require authentication so I don't have a logged in user either. The last option and probably the ugliest way would be to hardcode and maintain a list at server side so that I don't have do a database trip every time.

Comment: Does your tenant table include this identifier or not? The most obvious approach would be to add it there and look it up at the beginning of a session. The extra roundtrip should be negligible since no data has to go back to the client. If the performance of the lookup is a concern the tenant table can be made in-memory if it's not already.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, the identifier is in the tenant table itself. I don't have any session as the API is stateless, does it mean that after getting the tenant id, I should send it back-and-forth with each request/response? Good to know that the db trip is negligible in case the data is not going back to the client. By "making the table in-memory", do you mean that I should have the required data hard coded or there is another way to store it which don't require the app update, such as Azure Key-Vault?

Comment: I meant using a [memory-optimized table](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables). No hardcoding there. If you have no session at all, then yes, you must have *some* way of either passing the tenant along (and doing so securely so people can't spoof requests for other tenants) or looking it up according to IP, or whatever else. The in-memory table could be used to map whatever you do have to the ID the database needs; this should then be cheap and fast enough that it can be done with every request.

Answer (score 0):

Considering comments from @JeroenMostert I've decided to do a database trip as it won't be expensive because the data will not going back to client. But after getting some good knowledge and understanding I'll certainly consider using memory optimize table.